# How do i tell Layout that this Line is X amount of Centimeter/inches?

Tags: page-layout, layout, sketchup

Im new to layout and I Need to do some elevations for a design.
Im bringing an elevation drawing into Layout and I just want to be able to dictate the dimensions.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. CAD related software questions are generally off-topic here.  You might be better to ask this on the Sketchup/Layout user forum. https://forums.sketchup.com/c/layout/8 - or possibly on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/search?q=sketchup